# :nth-child combined with :not strange behavior

Tags: css, css-selectors

Hej Folks,

i'm stuck with CSS and the :nth-child and :not selector.

**The Situation:** 
I have a searchfield where the results are displayed below. When entering the site all results are already shown. For better reading each 2nd result row gets a highlight color unsing `:nth-child(odd)`

**The Goal:**
When a user enters a value into the search bar i want do hide (not remove!) all invalid rows. It works pretty fine by adding the class `__inivisible`. It just sets the `display` attribute to `none`.

**The Problem:** 
After adding the class `__invisible` the `:nth-child` selector won't work as expected. I have combined it with a `:not(.__invisible)` selector to exclude all irrelevant and invisible results. Thus he still counts them.

Maybe its a bit hard to understand, so here is a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/SHGp2/3/

i would expect that the 2 pink rows should be the only rows where he has to decide whether ist odd or even, so one should be pink and one should be blue.

if you don't understand what im talking about, disable the comment in the `__invisible` class. You will see two pink rows instead of one pink and one blue.

Maybe i got the function of the `:nth-child` selector wrong, if so, is there a way to get the thing working with pure CSS?

Thanks in advance! :)

P.S.
no JS in this fiddle ;)

Comment: You can't do this without javascript sadly :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nth-chlid` counts the children of the parent, regardless of whether they are visible, or have any other conditions applied to them. Unfortunately there is no way to do what you're trying here, as even `nth-of-type` only compares tag names.

Your best option is to completely remove the rows when they are filtered out. I would suggest making a clone of the table, and then you can clone this "template" whenever you need to get the original full table back.

Comment: Cloning is a bit “hardcore” for this, I think – if already using JS in some way (and the list reacting dynamically to search input suggest so), then I would just to the even/odd coloring of _visible_ items by JS as well, by adding alternating classes like `"even"`/`"odd"`.

Comment: damn :(  but i think this is a bad implementation, because i would expect that he counts all childs that are not .__invisable :( Everytime when you think you got CSS something like this happens ;)

Comment: dont worry folks, its no problem to sole this, im already using a template system and this task i really easy, is just hoped to increase my CSS skills ;)